# Fast lookup suffering from floating point inaccuracies

Tags: c#, algorithm, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Suppose I have equally spaced doubles (64 bit floating point numbers) `x0,x1,...,xn`. Equally spaced means that for all `i`, `x(i+1) - xi` is constant; call it `w` for width.

Given a number `y` in the range `[x0,xn]` I want to find the largest `i` such that `xi <= y`.

A naive approach would visit each `i` in turn (`O(n)`). Marginally better is to use a binary search (`O(log n)`).

A constant time lookup would be to calculate `(y-x0)/w` and cast it to an integer. However, this will occasionally give the wrong result due to floating point inaccuracy. E.g. Suppose there are 100 intervals of width 0.01 starting at 0.

```
(int)(0.29/0.01) = 28 //want 29 here
```

Can I retain the constant time lookup but ensure that the results are always identical to the binary search? Performing the calculation with decimals rather than doubles for 'w' and 'x0' seems to work here, but will it always work? I could always follow the direct lookup with a comparison with the `x`s either side, but this seems ugly and inefficient.

To clarify - I am given the `xi` and the value `y` as doubles - I cannot change this. But any intermediate calculation performed before returning the integer index can use any datatypes I like. Additionally, I can perform one-off "preparation" work in order to make the runtime calculation faster.

Edit: Apologies - turns out that I didn't check "equally spaced" properly - these numbers are often not "equally spaced" when their difference is calculated using floating point arithmetic.

Comment: `(int)(0.29/0.01 + 0.5) = 28` if you want to round it and not just truncate. (0.289999/0.01 = 28.999999 that gives 28 when truncatured)

Comment: 1) Rounding instead of truncating will reduce the probability of needing adjustments.  `(int)Math.Round(0.29/0.01)` 2) I'd use the index computation followed by a loop that adjusts it by stepping up/down until you're at the correct position. For sufficiently pathological cases, adjusting by a single step might not be enough. 3) The floating point spec for C# is so evil, that unless you cast from double to double in the right places (forcing a precision reduction to double), the above algorithm still might not *always* work.

Comment: @iKiWiXz better to be explicit and use Math.Round, Math.Floor, Math.Ceiling than try to force the cast to do it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're right, but I wasn't trying to give an answer, I just wanted to explain why.

Comment: If you have N doubles spaced equally by W, are you sure you need to store the actual doubles and not just the index of each, so that `xi = index * W`?  Then the solution would become trivial, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Mike - I'm not sure what you mean. Regardless of what format I'm given the `xi`s in, my fast lookup method still needs to return an index when given a double value y.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Rounding (to the nearest int) will give the wrong answer more often than truncating. I'm not looking for the nearest `xi`, but the largest one that is no bigger than `y`. If the `x`s are `0, 1, 2` and I look up `1.8`, I want the answer `1`, not the answer `2`.

Comment: @Rob Since the double `2.9` is smaller than the mathematical value 2.9, your expectation that it should be put into the 29 bucket may be wrong. Double is only the correct choice if small errors are acceptable. Else depending on context you'll either need `decimal` or some kind of arbitrary precision `Rational` type.

Comment: Basically, I was thinking the exact same thing that Tarik answered, considering it to be a trivial solution. If you want something even simpler than that, then boy, you are demanding!  C-:=

Comment: @CodesInChaos. The mathematical `0.29` doesn't come into it. `x29 = 0.29`, and `y=0.29` are both given to me as doubles, and hence neither is equal to the mathematical `0.29`. But they are equal to each other, and hence the binary search where `y` is compared with a number of `xi`s gives the answer 29, and so that's what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following

Calculate `(int)(0.29/0.01) = 28 //want 29 here`

Next, calculate back `i * 0.01` for i between 28-1 and 28+1 and pick up the one that is correct.

Comment: Yes, this is essentially what I hinted at when I mentioned comparing the x's either side.I want to avoid this if possible.

Comment: You said "Can I retain the constant time lookup but ensure that the results are always identical to the binary search?" - this would appear to answer your question in the affirmative.

Comment: You just need to look at 3 values. That's constant time.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean `equally spaced`? If can make some assumptions about the numbers, for example - that they increase on an interval, you can actually use median selction that is O(1) in the best case and O(log2(N)) in the worst case.

Comment: Equally spaced means that the double calculated as `x(i+1) - xi` is constant regardless of `i`.